# Display minutes with leading zero?

Tags: java, android

I am getting hours and minutes like `4:7 PM`, `5.30 AM`, where in the first one  is 4 hours 7 minutes. From 0 up to 10 minutes it shows like this. I need to change this to `4:07 PM`.

This is my code:

```
seekBar_startTime = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);

        seekBar_startTime.setProgress(0);
        seekBar_startTime.setMax(1440); //minutes in 24 hours
        seekBar_startTime.setProgress(1);
        final TextView textView_startTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progressValue, boolean fromUser) {
                    int minutes;
                    int hours;

                    minutes = progressValue % 60;
                    hours = progressValue/60;
                    String am_pm;
                    if (hours==24)
                    {
                        hours = hours-12;
                        am_pm="AM";
                    }
                    else if
                            (hours> 12)
                    {
                        hours= hours- 12;
                        am_pm = "PM";
                    }
                    else if (hours ==0) {

                        hours =hours+12;
                        am_pm = "AM";
                    }
                    else if (hours <12) {
                        hours = hours;
                        am_pm = "AM";
                    }
                    else if (hours ==0) {

                        hours =hours+12;
                        am_pm = "AM";
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        am_pm="PM";
                    }

                    start_Time = String.valueOf(""+hours+":"+minutes+am_pm);

                    textView_startTime.setText("Event Start Time :" + start_Time);
                }

            });
```

Comment: if(minutes < 10){ start_Time = String.valueOf(""+hours+": 0"+minutes+am_pm);} else {start_Time = String.valueOf(""+hours+":"+minutes+am_pm);} Do like this

Comment: It works ....Thank u

Answer (score 4):

Problem is you get minutes value, `int` variables does not keep left zeroes.

So:

- check when printing:
- use a `String` to represent minutes:

**USING A STRING**

```
String minutes;
minutes = String.valueOf(progressValue % 60).format();
minutes = String.format("%02d", number);
```

**PRINTING**

Change this:

```
start_Time = String.valueOf(""+hours+":"+minutes+am_pm);
```

For this:

```
if (minutes < 10) {
    start_Time = String.valueOf(""+hours+":0"+minutes+am_pm);
} else {
    start_Time = String.valueOf(""+hours+":"+minutes+am_pm);
```

Comment: great to hear... don't forget to mark this or any other answer as accepted to tell community you solved your issue and give some positive reputation to you and answerer.

Comment: After this process i need to covert 12 hours time to 24 hours...Because in database i have to store in 24 hours format....How to convert that at the end

Comment: can you please paste here the **exact** string that this method outputs? conversion must be done with `DateFormatter`....

Comment: Please check this link...i have doubt in this.......http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32433792/i-need-to-add-drop-down-bar-in-my-code

Answer (score 0):

Create a instance of a Calendar and set the hours and minutes. 
By using a calendar you can use a dateformatter to get time.

This way you can also get the time in a 24 hours format.